# Update MPI to the newest version

Tags: ubuntu, installation, version, mpi, openmpi

I'd like to upgrade my MPI to the newest stable one, that is the version 2.0.1. Before tring on my own I checked if something useful is on the [Open MPI site](https://www.open-mpi.org/).

The point 6 on the [FAQ page](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=building#install-overwrite) explicitly says that *installing one version of Open MPI does not uninstall another version*. To install a newer version, the site suggests one of four ways.

- *Install newer versions of Open MPI into a different directory*. I don't want to have both versions installed.
- *The make uninstall process from the build tree should completely uninstall that version from the installation tree, making it safe to install a new version into the same installation tree*. I don't think I have the build tree (nor the source tree; maybe I removed those folders following a guide like [this](http://edu.itp.phys.ethz.ch/hs12/programming_techniques/openmpi.pdf)), so I don't have a `make unistall` command to run.
- *Remove the old installation directory entirely and then install the new version.* This is the only thing I can do, since...
- ...the fourth way is not recommended, so I would avoid it.

Now the point is how can I locate the installation directory? If I `locate mpirun` or `mpifort` I find some result in several folders, many of them being not `.../openmpi/...`.

I'm actually interested in the answer to this question for both Ubuntu 15.10 and Mac OS X 10.11.6.

Comment: Please note that your question is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Managing software installations is more suitable to [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: @HristoIliev, should I delete this question and post it on Super User or wait for you to migrate it? Btw, there's no mpi-related tag on SU.

Comment: Leave it and see what the community thinks. But, in my opinion, this is a generic question about installing some piece of software and that this piece happens to be Open MPI does not make it MPI-specific. The MPI tag should be used for questions about programming with MPI and running MPI applications.

Comment: @HristoIliev, there's a recommendation in the FAQ page (*If you install a new version of Open MPI over an older version, this may not remove or overwrite all the files from the older version. Hence, you may end up with an incompatible muddle of files from two different installations -- which can cause problems.*) that I don't know if it is so common among applications. Apart from this, do you think I should cross post on SU and, in case of an answer, add a link to the present question?

Comment: I've flagged your question for moderator intervention. A moderator should be able to move it. In any case, you have to improve the question and prove information on how the existing version was installed. If you don't have the source code, then it probably came via a package and should be removed using the package manager.

Comment: No, I compiled it from source, then deleted the sources, unhappily. BTW, the [guide I linked](http://edu.itp.phys.ethz.ch/hs12/programming_techniques/openmpi.pdf) (I think it's similar to but not the one I followed) says "To uninstall OpenMPI just delete the folder opt/openmpi in your home directory and remove the last two lines from the .bashrc file in your home directory." I'm going to try in the night.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question but I would like to post an answer for future referece. In the fourth point of the FAQ, after describing the method that is not recommended, they state the following:

> Indeed, if you no longer have access to the original Open MPI a.b.c source and build trees, it may be far simpler to download Open MPI version a.b.c again from the Open MPI web site, configure it with the same installation prefix, and then run `make uninstall`. Or use one of the other methods, above.

Answer (score -2):

If what you want is to install the latest OpenMPI, without uninstalling your current one, you just install it in any directory you want. For instance, if you install it in a bin folder in your home, you do:

`$ configure --prefix=/home/bin <any_OpenMPI_options>`

`$ make all install`

Then, whenever you want to use this new version, you have to options:

1. You specify the whole path to the binary whenever you use `mpicc` or `mpirun`. For instance:

   `$ /home/bin/mpicc ...`

   `$ /home/bin/mpirun ...`
2. The other option is that you add the `/home/bin` path, where the new OpenMPI executables are, to the `PATH` environment variable. Of course, remember to add the `lib` folder, which could be also in `/home/bin/lib` to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: I explicitly wrote that **I don't want to have both versions installed**.